# Getting sting variables out of a class

Tags: c#

I'm doing a little c# project where im programming a little game, just to get better and convident with c#. The game is about a hero and I want to display the stats of the hero in a listbox. I've get and set methods for every variable, but if I want to add them to a string, it' simply adds "" or 0 for the int variables.

I changed some things around but it did not helped(I'm pretty new to programming)

The hero class:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Game
{
    class Hero : Character
    {
        int health, max_health, dmg, gold, rüstung;
        string name;
        public Hero(string name, int health, int max_health, int dmg, int rüstung, int gold) : base(name, health, dmg)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.health = health;
            this.max_health = max_health;
            this.dmg = dmg;
            this.gold = gold;
            this.rüstung = rüstung;
        }
        public void getsDamaged(int d)
        {
            d = d - rüstung;
            if (health - d > 0) health -= d;
            else health = 0;
        }
        public void heal(int h)
        {
            if (health + h < max_health) health += h;
            else health = max_health;
        }
        public int Gold
        {
            get { return gold; }
            set { gold = gold + value; }
        }
        public int Health { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Max_health{get;set;}
        public int Dmg { get; set; }
        public int Protection { get; set; }
    }   
}
```

and the method that should display the stats:

```cs
private void show_stats(Hero h)
        {
            string hero_name;
            hero_name = "Name: "+ h.Name;
            listBox1.Items.Add(hero_name);

            listBox1.Items.Add("HP: " + Convert.ToString(h.Health) + "/" +Convert.ToString(h.Max_health));
            listBox1.Items.Add("Dmg: " + Convert.ToString(h.Dmg));
            listBox1.Items.Add("Protection: " + Convert.ToString(h.Protection));
            listBox1.Items.Add("Gold: " + Convert.ToString(h.Gold);

        }//
```

As I said instead of displaying the actuall stats its says:

```
Name:
HP: 0/0
Dmg: 0
Protection: 0
Gold: 0
```

and the hero I added has none of these stats on 0

Comment: It looks like you are passing an empty hero object. You can test this by debugging and checking what "h" is in your "show_stats" method.

Comment: you have properties in your hero class but you aren't using it, instead you are using the fields. i.e. delete all lower starting case fields (int health, max_health, dmg, gold, rüstung) and use properties (the ones starting with uppercase)

Comment: Did you noticed that the field `health` is not the same as the autoimplemented property `Health`?

Comment: I would advise you NOT to use these constructions: `set { gold = gold + value; }` it implies that you are setting the value instead of adding.. Use a function instead! `public void AddGold(int amount) { Gold += amount; }` And check for bounds in the setter.

Comment: Aside from the problem at hand, are you sure you really want to have a variable name that is not only english but even contains german umlauts, which are not ASCII?

Comment: @Aziuth Agreed, usually bad practice. Btw I think you mean `that is not only not English` instead of `that is not only english` not only not sounds a bit weird but I think its what you mean

Comment: Maybe you should try an exercise that explains classes a bit. And the use of backing fields etc. I think that would help and you would not have this issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your constructor is setting member variables, but you are using automatic properties. These automatic properties don't use the member variables.

To fix the problem remove the member variables and use the properties directly. Your class will look something like this:

```
class Hero : Character
{
    int rüstung, gold;

    public Hero(string name, int health, int max_health, int dmg, int rüstung, int gold) : base(name, health, dmg)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Health = health;
        this.Max_health = max_health;
        this.Dmg = dmg;
        this.Gold = gold;
        this.rüstung = rüstung;
    }
    public void getsDamaged(int d)
    {
        d = d - rüstung;
        if (Health - d > 0) Health -= d;
        else Health = 0;
    }
    public void heal(int h)
    {
        if (Health + h < Max_health) Health += h;
        else Health = Max_health;
    }
    public int Gold
    {
        get { return gold; }
        set { gold = gold + value; }
    }
    public int Health { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Max_health{get;set;}
    public int Dmg { get; set; }
    public int Protection { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It's partly the problem, but not *the* problem.  Look at `Gold`, for example.

Comment: Did you noticed the `: base(name, health, dmg)`? Might be worth mentioning something about that.

Answer (score 2):

You have **never** touched your properties. change your properties to represent the fields data:

```
namespace Game
{
    Public class Hero : Character
    {
        int health, max_health, dmg, gold, rüstung;
        string name;
        public Hero(string name, int health, int max_health, int dmg, int rüstung, int gold) : base(name, health, dmg)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.health = health;
            this.max_health = max_health;
            this.dmg = dmg;
            this.gold = gold;
            this.rüstung = rüstung;
        }
        public void getsDamaged(int d)
        {
            d = d - rüstung;
            if (health - d > 0) health -= d;
            else health = 0;
        }
        public void heal(int h)
        {
            if (health + h < max_health) health += h;
            else health = max_health;
        }
        public int Gold
        {
            get { return gold; }
            set { gold = gold + value; }
        }
        public int Health { get { return this.heath; } }
        public string Name { get { return this.name; } }
        public int Max_health { get { return this.max_health; } }
        public int Dmg { get { return this.dmg; } }
        public int Protection { get; set; }
    }   
}
```